# createSqlQuery Hibernate, Java

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to write hibernate query (createSQLquery) in Java land
I have query but I bit lost how to create criteria for my query.

basically I have to transfer regular where clause to hibernate .add(Restriction)

for instance lets take:

```
where (name LIKE '%test%' or lastname LIKE '%test%') and (site_id = 2) and (date>=121212 and date <= 343343)

Query query = sess.createSQLQuery(sql).addScalar("ID", Hibernate.long);
query.add(Restrictions.or ( 
                            Restrictions.like("name", "%test%")
                            Restrictions.like("lastname", "Fritz%")
          ))
     .add(Restrictions.eq("site_id", new Integer(2)))
     .add(Restrictions.add(Restrictions.gr("date_start", 122122)
                       .add(Restrictions.le("date_end", 345433)));
```

I did not have chance to run it since do not have access to my environment now, just would love to figure out this.

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, you seem to be mixing a few different things.  Restrictions.eq is part of the Criteria framework, not sql queries.  Try reading http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html

Comment: but how do I do it for createSqlQuery in this case.. nothing here about it http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch18.html

Comment: you can't set restrictions like that on a SQLQuery, they're orthogonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, problem solved this way:

Query from XML - I put in where clause

```
<Applications>
    <Application name="AlertData">
        <Query name="alerts">
            <SQL>
                SELECT 
                    mr.measurement_date as measurementDate,
                    ........ // more data
                FROM measurement m
                    LEFT JOIN tags     ON mr.tag_id = tags.tag_id
                    .......... // more joins
                WHERE
                    mr.site_id = :siteid
                    $searchConstraints$ // just a string
                    $dateStartFragment$ // just a string                                  
            </SQL>
        </Query>
    </Application>
</Applications>
```

Next Java code:

```
 if (search != null && !search.isEmpty()) {   
            searchFragment = " AND (UPPER(field1) LIKE :search" +
                              " OR UPPER(field2)  LIKE :search)";           
  }


  sql = this.prepareQuery(sql, ImmutableMap.of(
      "searchConstraints", searchFragment,
      "dateStartFragment", dateStartFragment
  ));


   Query query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createSQLQuery(sql) 
   //more query here



 if (search != null && !search.isEmpty()) {    
     query.setString("search", "%" + search.toUpperCase() + "%");            
 }



public String prepareQuery(String queryString, Map<String, String> templateVars) {
     ST stringTemplater = new ST(queryString, '$', '$');

      for (String key : templateVars.keySet()) {
          stringTemplater.add(key, templateVars.get(key));
      }

      String renderedQuery = stringTemplater.render();
      return renderedQuery;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this

```
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(YourPojo.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
    criteria .add(Restrictions.or ( 
                        Restrictions.like("name", "%test%"),
                        Restrictions.like("lastname", "Fritz%")));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("site_id", new Integer(2)))
    criteria.add(Restrictions.add(Restrictions.gr("date_start", 122122)
                   .add(Restrictions.le("date_end", 345433)));
    return (criteria.list());
```

Comment: can I use createCriteria() with QueryManager?
I have right now sql query and create createSQLquery(sql).addScalar("id", Hibernate.long).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(POJO.class));
and after I have to apply restrictions.

Comment: if you want to use sql query use CreateSQLQuery otherwise use criteria

Comment: I understood it, but how do I apply WHERE to my query in this case. Cant believe that impossible. I mean add restriction if something is true.

Comment: No its not like that you can apply where clause on sql query .please go throuth this link   http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-queries-examples/